# Como funciona async/await do ES7?

Tags: javascript, assincronismo, ecmascript-6, promises, async-await

O ES7 permite usar uma nova sintaxe para trabalhar com Promises conhecida como funções async/await. Como posso utilizar estas funções e como elas são comparadas com funções que utilizam Promises para processar dados sequencias e em paralelo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A sintaxe de funções `async` são convertidas para `Promises` nativos do JavaScript, tornando-a compatível com as implementações existentes.

Para exemplificar vou deixar aqui duas Promises que vou utilizar:

```
// Retorna um usuário depois de 1 segundo.
function usuario(id) {
  const users = {
    1: {id: 1, nome: 'Marcos'},
    2: {id: 2, nome: 'Pedro'}
  };
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(users[id]), 1e3);
  });
}

// Retorna o cargo depois de 2 segundos
function cargo(idUsuario) {
  const cargos = {
    1: { titulo: 'Sobrinho do chefe' },
    2: { titulo: 'XGH Evangelista' }
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let usuario = cargos[idUsuario];
      if (usuario) resolve(usuario);
      else reject('Usuário não existe!');
    }, 2e3);
  });
}
```

Agora vamos criar algumas funções usando sintaxe async/await.

**Sequencial:**

```
async function cargoDoMarcos() {
  const user = await usuario(1);
  const cargo = await cargo(user.id);
  return cargo.title;
}
```

O código acima vai retornar uma Promise, que quando resolvida retorna o título do cargo do Marcos. Se fosse escrita como Promise seria:

```
function cargoDoMarcos() {
  return usuario(1)
    .then(user => cargo(user.id);
}
```

Apesar do código em forma de promessa ser mais curto no caso, o código da função async é muito mais simples de se entender quando lendo o código. Isso fica bem claro quando o código tem várias promessas em sequencia.

Mas e quanto a chamadas em paralelo?

**Paralelo:**

```
async function meusColegas() {
  // Chamei os dois sem o await
  let marcos = usuario(1);
  let pedro = usuario(2);

  // Agora eu vou usar esses objetos então vou esperar pela resposta deles:
  marcos = await marcos; // após 1 segundos vai continuar
  pedro = await pedro;   // já tem o pedro, imediatamente vai continuar
  return `${marcos.nome} e ${pedro.nome}`;
}
```

Se a gente usasse o await na chamada do usuário, a promessa iria aguardar o usuário do `marcos` por 1 segundo e então chamar pelo `pedro` o qual faria a aplicação aguardar por outro segundo.

Se fosse utilizando promesas ficaria assim:

```
function meusColegas() {
  let marcos = usuario(1);
  let pedro = usuario(2);
  return Promises.all([marcos, pedro])
    .then(colegas => `${colegas[0].nome} e ${colegas[1].nome}`);
}
```

Escrever no formato de Promise mais uma vez pode ser mais curto, mas é menos legível, claro que podemos escrever de forma mais verbosa usando Promise que pode se tornar mais legível, mas quando estamos falando de códigos reais, normalmente utilizar async vai tornar seu código muito mais legível e potencialmente mais simples.

**Rejeições com async:**

É possível rejeitar um resultado de função async utilizando `throw valor`, o resultado será o mesmo que usar `Promise.reject(valor)`.

```
async function nomeDoUsuarioInvalido() {
  const usuario = await usuario(3);
  // A partir desta linha, nada será executado, pois o usuario(3) foi rejeitado.
  return usuario.nome;
}
```

A função `usuarioInvalido` quando chamada vai ser rejeitada, executando o `usuarioInvalido().catch(erro => console.log(erro))` você pode ver o erro.

Mas para ignorar erros, você pode usar blocos de `try-catch` nas funções async, exemplo:

```
async function nomeDoUsuarioInvalido() {
  let usuario;
  let nome;
  try {
    usuario = await usuario(3);
    // A proxima linha será ignorada
    nome = usuario.nome;
  } catch (erro) {
      // erro = 'Usuário não existe!'
      nome = 'Ninguém';
  }
  // Este código será executado e vai retornar 'Ninguém'
  return nome;
}
```

Comment: O TypeScript (linguagem que compila para ES3, ES5 e ES6) resolve o suporte de async e await com as funções geradoras do ES6 (acho que é assim que diz... coroutines?) e promises.