# Usar closure como retorno de uma função

Tags: ajax, return, closures

Eu preciso utilizar uma variável de uma `closure` como retorno da função à qual essa `closure` está aninhada. Como consigo fazer isso?

`response` deve ser o retorno de `ajaxRequest()`:

```
function ajaxRequest(type, url) {
  const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()

  ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
      let response = parseToJson(ajax.responseText) // → JSON.parse(str)
      // ...
    }
  }

  ajax.open(type, url)
  ajax.send()

  // return response
}
```

`ajaxRequest` é chamado a partir de duas funções que contém os dados de requisição: `tradesRequest()` e `pricesRequest()`. Eu preciso do retorno destas duas funções para chamar uma terceira função, que terá como parâmetros as respostas das requisições das duas funções citadas acima.

```
function tradesRequest() {
  ajaxRequest(args) // args = type, url
}

function pricesRequest() {
  ajaxRequest(args)
}

function display(trades, prices) {
  // Esta função utilizará as respostas das funções acima.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ajaxRequest` não pode dar retorno síncrono porque o ajax é assincrono. Ou seja um cenário como:

```
function ajaxRequest(type, url) {
   // etc...
   return dados; // onde dados é o valor que veio do servidor
}
var resposta = ajaxRequest('algo', 'algo');
```

não é viável. Tens de usar lógica assíncrona.

Para fazer isso assíncronamente tens 3 hipoteses: [`callback`, `promises`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140883/129) ou [`funções assíncronas`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148687/129).

Deixo um exemplo, podes ler muito mais sobre as possibilidades nos links que indiquei em cima.

Exemplo:

```
function ajaxRequest(type, url, done) {
    const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()

    ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
            let response = parseToJson(ajax.responseText) // → JSON.parse(str)
            done(null, response);
        } else {
            done('Houve um erro!...');
        }
    }
    ajax.open(type, url)
    ajax.send()
}

ajaxRequest('clientes', '/admin.php', function(erro, resposta){
    if (erro) return console.log(erro);
    // quando esta callback correr, já vais ter a resposta disponivel
    alert(JSON.stringify(resposta, '\n', 4));
});
```

---

## Edit

(para contemplar a edição na pergunta com 3 funções)

Neste caso sugiro que uses `Promise`. Podes fazer algo assim:

```
function ajaxRequest(type, url, done) {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()
        ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
                let response = parseToJson(ajax.responseText) // → JSON.parse(str)
                res(response);
            } else {
                rej('Houve um erro!...');
            }
        }
        ajax.open(type, url)
        ajax.send()
    });
}

function tradesRequest() {
    return ajaxRequest('foo', 'bar');
}

function pricesRequest() {
    return ajaxRequest('alfa', 'beta');
}

function display(trades, prices) {
    // Esta função utilizará as respostas das funções acima.
}

Promise.all([tradesRequest, pricesRequest]).then(function(resultados) {
    // resultados é uma array
    var resultado1 = resultados[0];
    var resultado2 = resultados[1];
    display(resultado1, resultado2);
    
    // ou ainda melhor:
    display.apply(this, resultados);
}).fail(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: eu preciso do retorno de duas requisições para chamar uma nova função que irá exibir os dados; tentei usar callbacks, mas não consegui montar uma lógica que guardasse as respostas das duas requisições. Você tem alguma orientação de como usar callbacks para isso?

Comment: @LuanVicente se leres os links que coloquei na resposta ficas _"mestre"_ em callbacks e lógica assíncrona :) Se completares a pergunta com o problema que tens posso dar uma olhada.

Comment: eu editei a pergunta com uma explanação melhor do problema. Acredito que a solução seja algo como nesta [sua resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140631/passar-vari%C3%A1veis-para-view-ejs-de-consultas-distintas/140634#140634), mas nas minhas tentativas sempre tenho `undefined` como resultado.

Comment: @LuanVicente dei mais um exemplo. Agora tenho de ir dormir. Boa sorte! Se tiveres problemas escreve aqui que ajudo daqui a 9 horas :)

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda!