# Problema com Http Request Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http, async

Iae galera!

Olha, eu tenho um código aqui que é recebe os dados do usuário quando ele digita o CPF dele, comecei recentemente a usar o funções Async. a ideia do Async não seria somente executar a função de baixo quando a de cima for resolvida? Algo como:

```js
async teste() {
   await const dados = this.http
        .get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
            this.usuarioDados = res
         })
   console.log(this.usuarioDados)
}
```

Então o console.log só será executado quando a requisição for resolvida, certo ou errado?

Enfim...

O objetivo do meu código já foi explicado, ele está assim:

```js
async receberUsuario(usuario) {
    await this.http
        .get<UsuarioDados>(environment.url + environment.token + '&Metodo=alunoCheckCPF&AlunoCPF=' + usuario.cpf)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            usuario.numero_registros = response.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.Registros;

            if (usuario.numero_registros === 1) {
                const dados = this.http
                    .get<UsuarioDados>(environment.url + environment.token + '&Metodo=alunoCheckCPF&AlunoCPF=' + usuario.cpf)
                    .toPromise();
                dados.then(res1 => {
                    usuario.nome = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].nome_aluno;
                    usuario.id = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].id_aluno_main;
                    usuario.idNaAcademia = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].id_aluno_academia;
                    usuario.senha = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].aluno_senha;
                    usuario.nomeAcademia = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].academia_nome;
                    usuario.idAcademia = res1.ALUNO_ACADEMIA.AlunoDados[0].id_academia;

                    console.log(usuario.nome);
                });

                const contato = this.http
                    .get<UsuarioContatos>(
                    environment.url + environment.token + '&Metodo=alunoLoginContatos&AlunoIDMain=' + usuario.id + '&CttoValidacao=true'
                    )
                    .toPromise();
                contato.then(res2 => {
                    usuario.email = res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos
                        .filter((contato1) => {
                            return contato1.ID_TipoContato === '3';
                        });
                    usuario.celular = res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos
                        .filter((contato2) => {
                            return contato2.ID_TipoContato === '4';
                        });
                });

                this.armazenarUsuario(usuario);

                this.authLoginService.senhaExiste(usuario);
          } else {
            console.log('Não encontrado');
          }
        });
    console.log(usuario.nome);
  }
```

O que ele está fazendo? Ele está fazendo uma requisição, pegando o número de registros do Usuário, se for igual a 1, faz o resto da requisição, se igual a 0, dê um `alert('Usuário não encontrado')`, o resto da requisição está em 2 partes, dados e contato, então ele pega primeiro os Dados, como "nome, id, senha, nome da academia e etc" e da um `console.log` só para debug, depos faz outra requisição para receber os contatos. Porém o JSON está no seguinte formato:

```js
{
    "ALUNO_CONTATOS": {
        "Registros": 2,
        "Contatos": [
            {
                "ID_TipoContato": "3",
                "TipoDescricao": "Telefone celular",
                "Contato": "31993004686"
            },
            {
                "ID_TipoContato": "4",
                "TipoDescricao": "E-mail",
                "Contato": "luca.mqf@outlook.com"
            }
        ],
        "ErroMsg": false
    }
}
```

Note que o contato está no meio de um Array de objetos, eu preciso separar o email do celular, para que eu não coloque por índica, algo como:

```js
usuario.celular = res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos[0]
usuario.email = res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos[1]
```

Eu achei melhor fazer usar o `filter()`, então fiz:

```js
contato.then(res2 => {
                    usuario.email = res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos
                        .filter((contato1) => {
                            return contato1.ID_TipoContato === '3';
                        });
                    usuario.celular = res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos
                        .filter((contato2) => {
                            return contato2.ID_TipoContato === '4';
                        });
                });
```

E no final de tudo coloquei um console.log() no usuário.nome, que só deveria executar quando toda a requisição se resolver, por isso coloquei o Await lá em cima, mas estou recebendo os seguintes erros:

- O console.log do final está sendo executado primeiro e está retornando Undefined
- Erro com meu filtro: "TypeError: res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos.filter is not a function
  TypeError: res2.ALUNO_CONTATOS.Contatos.filter is not a function"

Como posso resolver esses problemas? Se a pergunta ficou confusa por favor me informar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Como eu posso utilizar o async/await do javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211505/como-eu-posso-utilizar-o-async-await-do-javascript) or [Como funciona async/await do ES7?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148686/como-funciona-async-await-do-es7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova o **.then** da **Promise** se deseja esperar que a requisição finalize antes de seu código prosseguir.

Fica assim:

```js
   async teste() {
       this.usuarioDados = await this.http
            .get(url)
            .toPromise();

       console.log(this.usuarioDados)
    }
```

Sugiro dar uma olhada nesse link, sugerido por Costamilam nos comentários: [Como eu posso utilizar o async/await do javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211505/como-eu-posso-utilizar-o-async-await-do-javascript)