# Async Await em JavaScript a bloquear execução de código síncrono

Tags: javascript, async-await

Se bem entendi, uma função declarada com a *keyword* async deve retornar uma promisse. No caso da função **async3()** temos 1 bilião de iterações, o que faz com que o valor a retornar demore um pouco mais. O que eu esperava que acontecesse é que, ao invocar a função **sync1()** e **sync2()** me mostrasse imediatamente o log na consola e, posteriormente, viria o log da função **async3()**. Contudo, o que verifico é que a função **sync1()** e **sync2()** só mostram após a **async3()** ter finalizado. Não seria suposto a função **async3()** estar a correr num outro thread ou fora do *event loop* sem bloquear a execução das outras funções?

Alguém me consegue clarificar o porquê deste comportamento?

```js
function sync1() {
  console.log(1);
}

function sync2() {
  console.log(2);
}

async function async3() {
  let iteration = 0;
  let number = 0;
  while (iteration <= 1000000000) {
    number = iteration;
    iteration++;
  }
  return number;
}

sync1();
sync2();
async3().then((val) => console.log(val));
```

A função **sync1()** e a **sync2()** só mostram na consola depois da **async3()** ter finalizado todas as iterações. Estou confuso.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como funciona async/await do ES7?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148686/como-funciona-async-await-do-es7)

Comment: @AugustoVasques Olá Augusto. Obrigado pela sugestão. É uma boa resposta, que discute os vários tipos de sintaxe em que podemos usar as promisses, contudo, aqui, neste caso em particular, eu queria perceber o porquê de eu ter um comportamento síncrono numa lógica assíncrona.

Comment: Sugestão de leitura: [Como programação assíncrona funciona em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ass%c3%adncrona-funciona-em-javascript/16960#16960)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um equivoco seu foi supor que uma função declarada com `async` não irá bloquear as outras funções apenas por ter sido declarada como `async`. Outro equívoco foi supor que essa função irá rodar em outro *thread* ou fora do *event loop*.

Não funciona assim, funções `async` rodam no mesmo *thread* e no mesmo *event loop*, além disso elas não rodam em paralelo, mas sim de modo concorrente. Isso significa que em momento nenhum você terá dois trechos do código sendo executados simultaneamente; a menos que você utilize *web workers*, o que não vou discutir aqui.

Uma função `async` irá de fato bloquear o restante do código enquanto ela precisar utilizar o processador, apenas quando funções `async` rodam uma operação de entrada/saída, as quais envolvem *system call*, é que elas podem rodar assíncrona - enquanto tal função espera pela resposta do *system call* ela entra num estado pendente, o que permite o processador a continuar rodando o restante do código sem ficar bloqueado pela operação que a sua função está esperando.

No seu código postado como exemplo não tem nada de assíncrono, declarar a função como `async` não trará benefício prático pois ela está consumindo os recursos do processador, e portanto bloqueando o restante do código. Então após todo esse esclarecimento fica a dúvida principal "*por que a função sync1() e a sync2() só mostram na consola depois da async3() ter finalizado todas as iterações*"?

Isso é porque... o que quer que você esteja utilizando para testar o código não está fazendo o *flush* do *stdout* no momento que você espera. Não tem razão para o código esperar o `async3` terminar para imprimir o `sync1` e `sync2`, de fato se você abrir o console do seu navegador e colar esse mesmo código, ele provavelmente irá imprimir *1* e *2* antes do `async3` terminar.