# Como renderizar um conteúdo assíncrono no React Native?

Tags: react, react-native

Sou novo no React Native e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação teste, onde eu estou precisando guardar alguns dados no dispositivo usando o Async Storage.

Consegui guardar os dados corretamente, porém quando eu tento pegar os dados para usar no meu componente eu não consigo, pois ocorre um erro de que não é possível renderizar um objeto em um trecho jsx. O código que me retorna esse erro é o seguinte:

```js
const renderItens = async () => {
   const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('CART');
   if(value != null){
      let parse = JSON.parse(value)
      return parse.map((item) => {
         return (
            trecho jsx mostrando o meu item.
         )
      })
   }else{
     return (
       trecho jsx falando que ta vazio o carrinho.
     )
   }

}
```

Eu não consigo fazer o `map` por causa desse erro. Se eu removo o `async` da função, o erro some e o meu `value` obtém a seguinte resposta: `{"_R:0","_N":0,"_W":null, "null":null}`, que não é o que eu quero.

No jsx eu chamo essa função da seguinte maneira:

```js
<ScrollView>{renderItens()}</ScrollView>
```

O que pode estar acontecendo e como eu posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve fazer as coisas separadamente, uma função `async` leva um tempo para dar um retorno, enquanto isso o componente já é renderizado. Uma solução seria:

1. Ter uma variável no *state*, onde você guardará os itens:

```js
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    }
```

2. Criar uma função para obter os dados do *storage*, chamando-a quando o componente é montado:

```js
    async getData() {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('CART');
        if (value != null) {
            let parse = JSON.parse(value);
            this.setState({ items: parse });
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }
```

3. Por fim, renderizar o conteúdo a partir da sua variável do *state* `items`:

```js
    render() {
        const { items } = this.state;

        if (items.length === 0) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>trecho jsx falando que ta vazio o carrinho.</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }

        return (
            <View>
                {items.map((item, index) => (
                    <View key={index}>
                        <Text>trecho jsx mostrando o meu item.</Text>
                    </View>
                ))}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma função assíncrona retorna uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), então ao utilizar `renderItens()` você estará renderizando essa `Promise` (Objeto) e não o resultado dela (JSX), já que ela ainda não foi resolvida. Veja [O que são promises (promessas) em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/100416) para mais detalhes.

Veja a diferença:

```js
const funcaoAssincrona = async () => "Retorno da função assíncrona";
const funcaoSincrona = () => "Retorno da função síncrona";

console.log(`Função assíncrona não resolvida: ${funcaoAssincrona()}`);
console.log(`Função síncrona: ${funcaoSincrona()}`);
```

### Obtendo o resultado correto com async/await

Veja que ao tentar exibir o conteúdo da chamada `funcaoAssincrona()`, é exibido `[object Promise]`, por isso o React Native lançou o erro de que não é possível renderizar um objeto em um trecho JSX. Se você tentasse exibir isso dentro de uma tag `<Text>`, conseguiria, mas seria exibido o mesmo que no `console.log()` acima.

Para obter o resultado correto, você precisaria fazer uso do `await`. O exemplo acima produziria o efeito correto dessa maneira:

```js
const funcaoAssincrona = async () => "Retorno da função assíncrona";
const funcaoSincrona = () => "Retorno da função síncrona";

const exibeRetornoAssincrono = async () => console.log(`Função assíncrona resolvida: ${await funcaoAssincrona()}`);

const exibeRetornoSincrono = () => console.log(`Função síncrona: ${funcaoSincrona()}`);

exibeRetornoAssincrono();
exibeRetornoSincrono()
```

Note que precisei fazer uso do `await` para exibir o resultado corretamente. Leia [Como funciona async/await do ES7?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148686/100416) para entender melhor sobre isso.

### Renderizando um conteúdo assíncrono

Quando existe algo assíncrono em um componente que será exibido na tela é comum fazer uso de estados de carregamento (*loading*) para o usuário entender o que está acontecendo, já que você **precisa renderizar algo** mesmo enquanto não obteve a `Promise` não foi resolvida.

Então seu componente poderia ser feito da seguinte maneira (com [Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), veja [O que é React Hooks?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/339671/100416)):

```js
function Cart() {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]); // Itens do carrinho
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // Começa o componente em estado de carregamento

  useEffect(() => {
    // Quando o componente é montado (`componentDidMount` de um componente Class),
    // carregue o conteúdo do Async Storage

    const loadCartItems = async () => {
      const jsonItems = await AsyncStorage.getItem('CART');
      if (value == null) {
         setCartItems([]); // Nenhum item encontrado
      } else {
         setCartItems(JSON.parse(jsonItems)); // Os itens encontrados
      }
      setIsLoading(false); // Atualiza o estado de "loading" do componente
    }

    loadCartItems();
  }, []);

  // Esse método não é mais assíncrono
  const renderItens = () => {
    if (cartItems.length === 0){
      return <Text>Carrinho vazio</Text>
    } else {
      return cartItems.map(item => <Text>Item: {item}</Text>)
    }
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Text>Carregando...</Text> // Informa o usuário que está carregando
  }

  return <ScrollView>{renderItens()}</ScrollView>
}
```

Se você não entende o uso do [`useState`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) ou do [`useEffect`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), veja as documentações deles.